# Behavior of delete different for a pointer and array

Tags: c++, arrays

I stumbled on this problem while tinkering with old school arrays. An interesting one though:

```
a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
a[][] = {{1,2,3,4}, {4,5,6,7}, {8,9,10,11}, {12,13,14,15}}
```

Consider 2 scenarios:

1.)

```
void func(int *a) { //passing a 1D array
   a[1] = 100; //modified an element here
   delete a;  //This would have no effect on the array outside this function. 
}
```

2.)

```
void func(int (*a)[4]) { //passing a 2D array
   a[1][2] = 100; //modified an element here of 2D array
   delete a;  //Would have an effect on the outside. Would delete a[0][0]'s memory outside.
}
```

Question is why?
In 1.) pointer shall point to an array variable memory hence, the delete signature won't clear the memory a[0]?

In 2.) the signature of parameter and passed variable match exactly hence the delete would indeed delete the memory held by local variable?

Any pointers here?

Comment: Why are you calling `delete`?  You never call `delete`/`delete[]` unless you call `new`/`new[]`

Comment: Both cases are undefined behavior, since the memory did not come from `new`.  There's no why beyond that.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here - @GameOfChess obviously forgot (or didn't know) that you have to allocate with `new` for `delete` to have defined behavior.  On the contrary, I think this question could be a very useful one to future Googlers who run into this problem.

Comment: Thank you all for answering this but I hoped for some deep responses. 
1.) I understand delete has to be used in conjunction with new. However, I am going deeper than that and investigating undefined behavior.
2.) Here, delete isn't that illogical. See, the pointer a as parameter in the function under scenario 1 would anyhow be allocated on the stack when this function is called. Point is this would, under normal circumstances be deleted by compiler after function terminates. My point was to see what happens if I delete it before that, inside the function itself.

Comment: 3.) Please, read the two functions carefully and try running it. I am looking for explanations for different behavior in the 2 scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking undefined behavior on multiple levels.  Calling `delete` on an array rather than `delete[]`...and calling any form of `delete` on an object not allocated with `new`.

Your program can do anything it wants.

Comment: Yes. I was wondering about that ANYTHING, and trying to figure out why that ANYTHING  was different under two scenarios.